# how square brackets works in map function javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {a:{bb:"mm"},b:{bbb:"bb"}}
var v= Object.entries(a)

// a print array items value that is fine
v.map((a,b)=>{console.log(a)})

// print the index that is fine

v.map((a,b)=>{console.log(b)})

// why it print 
//
//{bb: "mm"}
//{bbb: "bb"}
v.map(([a,b])=>{console.log(b)})

//output
```

https://jsbin.com/zevuqedupa/edit?html,js,console,output ..why not print `index`

Hi
my question why it is printing in `object`.Is it destructing of es2015? is it es6 part ?

Comment: Doesn't a square bracket denote an index/property name? You're basically calling `console.log(v[a]); console.log(v[b]); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object.entries(..)` method accepts an object and returns an array of key-value pairs, that are other arrays where the first element is the key and the second element is the value.

In this case, the `v` variable will be:

```
[['a', {bb: 'mm'}], ['b', {bbb: 'bb'}]];
```

The `map` method will iterate on each of the inner array.

So, on the first iteration it will receive, as first parameter:

```
['a', {bb: 'mm'}]
```

On the second iteration ti will receive, as first parameter:

```
['b', {bbb: 'bb'}]
```

Now we go to destructuring. When you pass the square brackets in the first parameter, you say:

Hey, the first parameter will be an array, let `a` be the first element of the array and let `b` be the second element of the array.

You print b, so you print the second element of the array at each iteration, and that is the value.

If you want, you can also print the index, since `[a, b]` is the first parameter altogether.

```
v.map(([a,b], index) => {console.log(`value: ${b}, index: ${index}`)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(a,b)=>{console.log(b)}
```

Expects 2 parameters named a and b and is called like f(a,b);

```
([a,b])=>{console.log(b)}
```

Expects and array and names the 0 and 1 indexes a and b and is called like f([a,b])